# Can anything be done if a single user is downvoting several posts in a row?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, serial-voting

I’ve taken a look at my reputation and believe a single user is downvoting several of my posts in a row.

Normally I would ignore this but my reputation is low. (I wish to place a bounty on a recent question.)

How do I get mods to investigate?

Comment: Flag the mods (from one of the downvoted posts) so they can take a look at it.